# event.preventDefault -- in Firefox, without jquery

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling

This works in Chrome:

```
<a href="#" onclick="myFunction()">Aaa</a>

function myFunction() {
  event.preventDefault();
  //.........
```

But in FireFox event isn't defined. How can I get it to work in Firefox without using jquery?

**update**:

```
function myFunction(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

how will event arrive to myFunction if it's not been passed to it from onclick?

Comment: `function myFunction(event) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **lack a parameter** there, which is the event.

```
function myFunction(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("It worked");
}
```

Also, in your `onclick` attribute of the anchor tag, pass the event as argument:

```
<a href="#" onclick="myFunction(event)">Aaa</a>
```

To verify that it solved the problem, here's a runnable code snippet:

```html
<a href="#" onclick="myFunction(event)">Aaa</a>

<script>
function myFunction(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("It worked");
}
</script>
```

Comment: why are you trying to guess?

Comment: @Jio I added a snippet that you could run. (Hint: It worked)

Comment: for me, locally, still not.

Comment: @Jio Don't tell me that you forgot to put `<script>` tag?

Answer (score 1):

```
function myFunction(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}

<a href="#" onclick="myFunction(event)">Aaa</a>
```

You have to specify event object in your onclick function, for event object to get passed.